# Meteor.js service-worker unsupported MIME type ('text/html')

Tags: meteor, service-worker

Right out of the box version 1.4 getting an error message in the console:

[image]

Comment: Please give us more information about this error if you want some help. What did you do - was it a new project, or a project you had just upgraded?

Comment: Completely new project. Just downloaded meteor, ran meteor create simple_app and then meteor to start the server...

Comment: Let me guess, you are on Windows?

Comment: Nope :) MacBook Pro...

Comment: 10.11.6 El Capitan

Comment: This error is something chrome is complaining about - you are not running this under https are you?

Comment: No ***http://localhost:3000/*** (it's in the error message as well - 2nd line of the screen shot) - no issues in safari, just checked...

Comment: Any chance this is caused by a chrome extension? Try incognito mode.

Comment: @ MasterAM - you were correct - in incognito it's fine. I wonder which extension it could be... I disabled all the extensions but the error is still showing up.... hmmmm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the service worker in the /public folder worked for me.